# No permission to downloaded files, only original files

Tags: macos, permissions, osx-mavericks

I'm working on a local server and whenever I copy something to the `images`- or `fonts`-folder, I get the following error:

```
**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access /resources/foldername/images/image.png on this server.
```

This only happens when I directly save a file I download from the internet, or when I move it from my `Downloads`-folder (after downloading it from the internet).

I found out it has to do with permissions: those unreadable files have the following permissions

- Me / Read & Write
- staff / Read only
- everyone / No access

How do I make it, so those files get the right permissions from the start? If I open an image in Photoshop for example, and then resave it under another name, it has the right permissions without me changing something. Does this have to do with some settings in Chrome?

Running Mac OS X Mavericks

Answer (score 0):

After trying with self-hosted files and different browsers, I found out that it (the changing of permissions) only happens in Chrome. Apparently, this is a known bug and should not happen for files for permanent storage and only for temporary items.

It is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409416) and should get fixed in the future. For now, there's nothing else we can do than wait.